# Customized mass installation

Tags: networking, live-usb, tftp, netinstall

I've been trying to find out how to solve this for quite a while now and finally I ended up here hoping to get some help!

I have a USB-drive which is working well, but I would like to use that image on the network instead and was wondering if that's possible with some neat boot options. Can I set up a TFTP server hosting that image and install it over the network the same way is I would do with the USB-drive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are many ways to do it but I would recommend to have a look at the [FOG Project](https://fogproject.org/).

The basic steps would be:

- Create a FOG server (I use a Virtualbox)
- Install a machine with your USB
- Add that machine as a host to FOG
- Change the machine BIOS to boot from the network.
- Upload the image (creates an image of the machine in FOG)
- Add any other machines you want to install as FOG hosts and set them up to boot from the network.
- Create tasks to download your image to those hosts.